# IIS and Per Directory Compression

Tags: iis, compression

It's a bit unusual question, but the 3rd party app we're using is having all textual files without an extension (.js, .css, etc...).

Is there a way to specify a directory where compression is mandatory for all files?

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. please post more details information about your requirement. and you said that all your textual files have no extension, is this in the url?

Comment: Yes, what I am trying to accomplish is have all the files under directory X be treated as static textual content and as such have them compressed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your looking for the `<location>` element. You set the site wide defaults as normal, then add a `<location path="x">` element with the folder specific settings and they are only applied to the path specified (and its children).

```
<configuration>

    ...

    <system.webServer>
        <httpCompression ...>
             <!-- Site wide default compression settings -->
        </httpCompression>
    </system.webServer>

    ...

    <location path="path/to/folder" >
        <system.webServer>
            <httpCompression ...>
                 <!-- override settings for requests starting "path/to/folder" -->
            </httpCompression>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```